# Pandas DataFrame throwing ValueError

Tags: python, sql, excel, pyodbc

I am a new-ish programmer trying to convert sql to excel as a side project. It uses a Pandas DataFrame. The command going into it is
`df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=columns)`
the variables going into this are

```
data: [('300       ', None, '300.05    ', 'test      '), ('300       ', None, None, None), (None, None, '300.05    ', None), (None, None, None, 'ID::4     ')]
columns: ['Num', 'Str', 'Float', 'ID']
```

I can't tell what might be throwing the ValueError in this. Please help if at all possible!

I am also using pyodbc with driver `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` and Microsoft SQL Server 19, if that helps.

Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1678, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))
  File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 3284, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 2792, in __init__
    super().__init__(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 128, in __init__
    "{mgr}".format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs))
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 4

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Py\pyxl\pyxl.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), None, columns, None, None)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 464, in __init__
    mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 213, in init_ndarray
    return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
  File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1688, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1719, in construction_error
    "Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(passed, implied)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 1), indices imply (4, 4)
```

Comment: Do note: pandas supports direct querying with [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html).

Comment: Is it possible to have a pyodbc connection work with read_sql? @Parfait

Comment: Yes. Simply pass the `pyodbc` connection into *con* argument of `read_sql`.

Answer (score 0):

You give the dataframe a list for the first col, but you initiate 4. So at least that is how I understand the error.

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Num": listNumValues, "Str": listStrValues, "Float": listFloatVlálues, "ID": listIDValues})
```

If you supply a dataset that looks like your data from sql then I can help you to convert it.